# How to bundle windows visual studio VSIX with other built application?

Tags: package, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I found that the windows visual studio extension is targeted to .net framework and only .net framework (which seems not clearly described in the docs?), after switching our custom mono debugger  extension to .net 7.0, with framework not compatible (between vsix project's .net framework 4.8 and debugger project's .net 7.0) error when building the vsix project.

If I switch the debugger project target back to .net framework 4.8 then I can build the extension along with the debugger and create a vsix bundle them togeter successfully.

I tried the previewing visual studio extensibility tools: the out-of-process solution, but the out-of-process way seems not have access to the dte object, thus no way to send the debug adapter launch command. If I use the in-process solution, then we head back to the .net framework target :(

The mono debugger extension is a "3rd party executable file" that launched by visual studio debug adapter. If I manually paste the .net 7.0 version mono debugger to the extension install location, the extension can still work with the debugger. I manage the debugger project and the vsix project within a solution is for easier project management only, in fact they are not referenced directly in code.

I switched our mono debugger project to .net 7.0 is for trying to upgrade our toolset to the newest unified framework (every other tool in our team are upgraded to .net 7.0).

TL;DR, how can we bundle a none .net framework targeted project along with a windows visual studio extension, which is targeted to .net framework only? Or how can we integrate/bundle/add built exe,dlls into the vsix container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some solutions from other stackoverflow answers such as add dlls using vsixmanifest, but it can only add dll file, and the way it handle asset file seems not quite right, it just copy the dll to vsix project folder once, meaning it won't get updated when the dll's project rebuild.

Here I managed to bundle the files in a wonky way:
I create a publish folder under vsix project folder,
then copy the published debugger project file to it, add them as existing file to vsix project, and configure them as vsix content, copy to vsix,
then add a pre-build event for the vsix project, publishing our debugger project and output to this publish folder.
With process above, I can package the published file into vsix when trigger vsix project build.
For anyone have similar issue, you can have a try.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! You can click '✔' to accept your answer. See [can I answer my own question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :) It will also help others to solve the similar issue.